# Is it possible to attach SSL certificate to this WebBrowser Component in Codename One?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, codenameone

I need to open Web page with help of WebBrowser component in the Codename One project.

```
    Form form = new Form();
    form.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
    browser.setURL("{Some URL}");
    form.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, browser);
    form.show();
```

I have this sample it works for http. But how is it possible to attach SSL certificate, especially when it is not trusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support attaching a custom ssl certificate at the moment. You can use https but untrusted sites are problematic on a mobile device.

Comment: It is interesting for me, the features like this e.g. custom certificate support and camera preview will be available one day or they never planned to implement?

Comment: Camera capture is available today, custom certificates are a difficult subject on the devices themselves. Notice you can use native interfaces to do anything you want in the native platform http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: To be honest I was talking about camera preview, not about capture, because I've already checked the samples and docs from you. About native interfaces I know as well). Anyway thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, camera preview and more complex manipulations are still unavailable unless you use native interfaces.